# How can I restrict customer accounts to a specific store view?

Tags: customer, customer-account, magento-2.2.5, website-restriction

If a customer registered on a specific storeview, it has to use the account only on that storeview. So I want to turn off the shared customer accounts. If a customer tries to log in with that account on another storeview, there must be an error which says that the account doesn't exist.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should have each storeview in a separate website. Then:

1.- go to:

```
System > Configuration
```

2.- Click on `customer configuration` left tab, under the `customers` options group

3.- In the `account sharing options` area, select `Per Website` option for the `Share Customer Accounts` select.

The storeviews that share website will share the accounts. And the storeviews' accounts that are in different websites will not be shared.